# Statically Linking a GCJ Application on Ubuntu Natty

Tags: java, linker, linker-errors, static-linking, gcj

I'm trying to statically link a GCJ application and it looks like theres some misconfiguration somewhere. I'm just using the standard gcj installation on natty and I have both libgcj11 and libgcj11-dev installed.

My test application is:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

I do:

```
gcj -static-libgcj --main=HelloWorldApp HelloWorldApp.java
```

then i get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcj
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Evidently GCJ isn't all there, but I would caution you against using it in any case. It isn't Java; it isn't complete; it probably never will be; it is incompatible in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

Distros generally do not ship libgcj.a.  Static linking does not work extremely well with gcj, anyway, mostly because not all of the class dependencies can be found -- compiled-in resources and also the use of reflection in the core library cause things to go missing at link time, unless you take special care to link them in by hand.

Comment: Ok showing up late for this conversation, but I came across the same problem.  If one wanted to try linking, where would one get libgcj.a?